# Can't get new files when adding files to a directory

Tags: java, eclipse, file, jetty

I'll post my code first:

```
private String path = ServerConfigProperties.getProperty("pathToDir");

public load(String path) {
    File mainDir = new File(path);
    for (File subDir : mainDir.listFiles()) {
        if (subDir.isDirectory()) {
            System.out.println(subDir.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

`mainDir` only holds the correct list of sub directoriesonly if I use eclipse `clean`.  For example, I can have a list of sub directories inside of `mainDir`.  When I run the code, the sub directories will all be there.  When I add more directories in with Windows Explorer and run the code again, the same list is printed out as if I had not added a new directory into the main directory.  If I then stop the code, run `clean` in eclipse, and restart my code, it finally picks up the newly added directories.  Is there any way for `mainDir` to maintain the up to date directory list during runtime?

EDIT: 
This is running on a jetty server.  It is not desirable to have to restart the server every time a new directory is added.  `load(path)` is called at different times in the server, so why doesn't it see the newly added directories between the calls to `load(path)`?

Comment: what path are you searching?  Is this a source path, or a derived path (eclipse term) with derived contents?

Comment: The path is grabbed from a properties file.  The path is then set by this `ServerConfigProperties.getProperty("pathToDir");`

Comment: Again, what path are you searching.  Not how you get that path, or how you configure that path, but what specific path?

Comment: When checking the directory attributes in eclipse, is `Derived` checked?

Comment: `C:\workspaces\antbuild\stephen\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\srv\WEB-INF\classes\part`

Comment: not sure how to find `Derived` or even attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contents in `WEB-INF/classes` is managed by many various components, some in Eclipse, some in Jetty, some in your build tools.
Accessing those contents, on disk, using standard java File I/O, isn't recommended when you are in the Servlet API.

Content within that directory is mainly accessed via the Classloader (using either [getResource()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#findResource%28java.lang.String%29) or [loadClass()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#loadClass%28java.lang.String%29).

Do not put dynamic content in that directory.

What is likely happening, is you are creating it in your project tree, eclipse goes through its build lifecycle, content either gets compiled or copied into the `WEB-INF/classes` output directory of your project.  Eclipse then either builds a war and deployes, or does an in-place deploy.  Then Jetty and the servlet spec kicks in and it ALSO unpacks (if needed), moves around, creates work directories, and temp directories and starts to manage the application using the requirements of the Servlet Spec.

If you want to manage dynamic content, at runtime, you have a few options.

1. If you want Jetty to be able to serve the content to a HTTP client, then do not put this content anywhere inside of the `WEB-INF` tree (that entire tree is access denied, per the Servlet Spec).
2. If you want Jetty, and its [DefaultServlet](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/servlet/DefaultServlet.html), or [DefaultHandler](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/server/handler/DefaultHandler.html), or [ResourceHandler](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/server/handler/ResourceHandler.html) to serve the content, you can put it anywhere on disk outside of the `WEB-INF` tree  (you just have to configure the appropriate servlet or handler to use that directory)
3. If you want to manage the directory contents yourself, even serving to HTTP Clients, then you can put it anywhere on disk outside of the `WEB-INF` tree, as there are many processes that manage that tree and there are no guarantees that the tree will remain unmolested by something outside of your control.

Some examples of configuring for #2 if using embedded mode jetty.

- DefaultServlet - [OnServletContext.java](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.0.4.v20130625/examples/embedded/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/embedded/OneServletContext.java)
- DefaultHandler - [ExampleServer.java](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.0.4.v20130625/examples/embedded/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/embedded/ExampleServer.java)
- ResourceHandler - [FileServer.java](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.0.4.v20130625/examples/embedded/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/embedded/FileServer.java)
- Custom File Server - [FastFileServer.java](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.0.4.v20130625/examples/embedded/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/embedded/FastFileServer.java)

Comment: Thanks, did not know about how it cannot handle dynamic content there.  I am going to work on implementing the directory structure to be outside of the WAR.  Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

This is typically a problem if you've compiled a JAR.

Netbeans will look in the bin folder for a pre-compiled object unless you tell it otherwise.

I would just stick with Clean + Run.